# How should I do an aggregate?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an array with products(objects) inside. It looks like:

```
[
 {_id: 123, name:'first', category:'Vape', property:[
   {key:'brand', values:'Eleaf'},
   {key:'mechmode', values:'some'},
   {key:'color', values:['red', 'blue']},
   {key:'batrtype', values:'some2'},
 ]},
{_id: 1234, name:'second', category:'Vape1', property:[
   {key:'brand', values:'Eleaf1'},
   {key:'mechmode', values:'some'},
   {key:'color', values:['black']},
   {key:'batrtype', values:'some2'}
 ]},
{_id: 12345, name:'third', category:'Vape3', property:[
   {key:'brand', values:'Eleaf3'},
   {key:'mechmode', values:'some'},
   {key:'color', values:['green', 'yellow']},
   {key:'batrtype', values:'some2'}
 ]},
{_id: 123456, name:'fourth', category:'Vape', property:[
   {key:'brand', values:'Eleaf'},
   {key:'mechmode', values:'some'},
   {key:'color', values:['red', 'green']},
   {key:'batrtype', values:'some2'}
 ]}
]
```

Request from client

```
{category:'Vape', body:{brand:'Eleaf', color:'red'}}
```

How should I do an aggregate in mongo to get products which have brand = 'Eleaf'
and color = red in according to request?

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Is that array stored as a single field in a document, or is it a list of documents in the collection?

Comment: it's a list of documents in the collection

Answer (score 1):

[bgraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8133274/bgraham)'s answer is exactly right if you are using `find`.  To do the same thing in an aggregation pipeline, use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), such as:

```
db.aggregate([{$match:{
   category: "Vape",
   $and: [ 
     { property: { $elemMatch: { key: "brand", value: "Eleaf" }, 
     { property: { $elemMatch: { key: "color", value: "red" } 
   ]
}}])
```

You could then add to the array any additional pipeline stages you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
db.products.find({ 
    category: "Vape",
    $and: [ 
         { property: { $elemMatch: { key: "brand", value: "Eleaf1" }, 
         { property: { $elemMatch: { key: "color", value: "red" } 
    ]})
```

I'm not sure the structure of your data is best practice. It might be easier if they were fields called "brand" with a value of "color" instead of key/value pairs.